# Coffeescript function on a rails page rendered via JS

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

this is a small issue and i am sure i am doing something wrong. I have a page that is being rendered via a JS response from one of the controller actions in Rails 3.

When this page renders it has an element on it called "stakeholder_add" (its a text box)

In coffeescript i have a function that does simply

```
$ ->
    if $('#stakeholder_add').length > 0
        alert "Hello"
```

this is not firing on page render. If i put the same element on a page that is being rendered via a HMTL response the event fires via coffeescript.

So the question really is

1. why is the event not firing via a JS render and
2. How to make this work

Comment: `$ ->` is equivalent to jquery ready(document), so that code will run when your html loads in the browser, if you are returning js from a rails action that is probably not going to reload the page (ajax) so that code will never run; maybe you want to put in a function and call the function when the ajax request returns?

Comment: Thanks Mr. Newton. That seemed to have done the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting a space and tabs between lines:

```
jQuery ->
  if $('#stakeholder_add').length > 0
    alert "Hello"
```

Comment: OP had not properly formatted the source for SO; I edited it to wrap it in an SO code block. Also, since it works when rendering via HTML, it would have been a good idea to check the question source first to see if it was a simple inability to format for SO.

Comment: Neon - thanks for your answer. Dave was right - it was a logic error in my code.